# Get the level of a specific logger in python

Tags: python, logging

For the sake of unit testing, I would like to know the level of a specific logger (`logging.Logger` instance). The goal is to modify a logger temporarily in the context of a test to log all levels, and then set it back to its previous level. I cannot find a safe way of finding this *previous level*.

This object has a `getEffectiveLevel()` that returns the level **if it has been set** or else goes up the tree to return the first non-zero level it encounters. This method is no good to me, because I won't know if the returned value is a parent's level or the actual logger.

I cannot find another method.

Comment: `logger.level` gets you the logger's current level but keep in mind that a logger might have handlers attached which may have also set a log level.

Comment: Do you need to find the previous level? Can't you just recreate the loggers after each unit test case is complete? Part of unit testing is this _resetting of all initialization_ before each test case runs, so all run without side-effects from previous cases

Comment: @slezica, I'm not initializing the logger myself in the test, I'm importing it from the module being tested. The goal is to verify the correct number of warnings are logged in specific situations (and a secondary goal is to silence the logger to keep a clean test output).

Comment: @orangeInk You made me realize that I'm already using a handler to do my test, so I can probably just work with the level of my custom handler and leave the logger level alone.

Comment: Nope, nevermind, setting the handler level does not work. Levels ignored by the logger never reach the handler.

Comment: So the solution seems to be `Logger.level`. But  this attribute is undocumented, AFAIK, so it's a potentially risky solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is to check the  `logger.level` attribute (undocumented), keep a copy of its value, restore it at the end.

The full code, to show how it is used in a context manager counting the number of logged messages:

```
class TestLogging(logging.Handler):
    """Context checking the number of logging messages from a specified Logger.
    It disables propagation of logging message while running.
    This is meant to be used as a with statement, for example:
    >>> with TestLogging(logger, error=2, warning=0):
    >>>     pass  # Run tests here expecting 2 ERROR and no WARNING from logger
    ...
    :param logger: Name or instance of the logger to test.
                   (Default: root logger)
    :type logger: str or :class:`logging.Logger`
    :param int critical: Expected number of CRITICAL messages.
                         Default: Do not check.
    :param int error: Expected number of ERROR messages.
                      Default: Do not check.
    :param int warning: Expected number of WARNING messages.
                        Default: Do not check.
    :param int info: Expected number of INFO messages.
                     Default: Do not check.
    :param int debug: Expected number of DEBUG messages.
                      Default: Do not check.
    :param int notset: Expected number of NOTSET messages.
                       Default: Do not check.
    :raises RuntimeError: If the message counts are the expected ones.
    """

    def __init__(self, logger=None, critical=None, error=None,
                 warning=None, info=None, debug=None, notset=None):
        if logger is None:
            logger = logging.getLogger()
        elif not isinstance(logger, logging.Logger):
            logger = logging.getLogger(logger)
        self.logger = logger

        self.records = []

        self.count_by_level = {
            logging.CRITICAL: critical,
            logging.ERROR: error,
            logging.WARNING: warning,
            logging.INFO: info,
            logging.DEBUG: debug,
            logging.NOTSET: notset
        }

        super(TestLogging, self).__init__()

    def __enter__(self):
        """Context (i.e., with) support"""
        self.records = []  # Reset recorded LogRecords
        self.logger.addHandler(self)
        self.logger.propagate = False
        # ensure no log message is ignored
        self.entry_level = self.logger.level * 1
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        """Context (i.e., with) support"""
        self.logger.removeHandler(self)
        self.logger.propagate = True
        self.logger.setLevel(self.entry_level)

        for level, expected_count in self.count_by_level.items():
            if expected_count is None:
                continue

            # Number of records for the specified level_str
            count = len([r for r in self.records if r.levelno == level])
            if count != expected_count:  # That's an error
                # Resend record logs through logger as they where masked
                # to help debug
                for record in self.records:
                    self.logger.handle(record)
                raise RuntimeError(
                    'Expected %d %s logging messages, got %d' % (
                        expected_count, logging.getLevelName(level), count))

    def emit(self, record):
        """Override :meth:`logging.Handler.emit`"""
        self.records.append(record)
```